# App Engine Returning Error 500 on Post Requests from

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

I am getting error 500 on every second POST request made from a browser (chrome and firefox) irrespective of whether it is a Jquery Post or Form submissions, app engine is alternating between error 500, and successful post. The error 500 are not appearing anyway in the logs.

I have tested this with over 5 different post handlers, the errors are only occurring on production not on the Local SDK server.

Note that the requests are perfectly successful when made from a python script using the requests module.

Comment: It turned out to be a a strange issue with my network (android hotspot), I still have no idea what network issue could result in HTTP ERROR 500s for some POSTs only, but the problem stopped immediately I connected to another network. (The issue affected not only my Site, but as I learned later, all sites when accessed from a browser, e.g I had to submit discuss comments twice (1 fail, 1 success)). Therefore, this question is likely not a good fit for stackoverflow, I will leave that decision to the moderators

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing anything in your server logs about the error, that suggests to me that you *might* have a configuration error in one of your `.yaml` files. Are GET requests working? Are you sure that you are sending your POST requests to an endpoint that is handled by your application? Check for typos in your JavaScript and application Route definitions, and check for a catch-all request handler (e.g. `/*`) that might be receiving the request and failing to respond.

Sharing the contents of your `app.yaml`, your server-side URL routes, and a snippet of your JavaScript would really help us to help you.

Comment: It turned out to be a a strange issue with my network (android hotspot), I still have no idea what network issue could result in HTTP ERROR 500s for some POSTs only, but the problem stopped immediately I connected to another network. (The issue affected not only my Site, but as I learned later, all sites when accessed from a browser, e.g I had to submit discuss comments twice (1 fail, 1 success))